# GCC Mac OS X framework search path: /System/Library before /Library?

Tags: macos, gcc

I'm trying to compile a project on Mac OS X that links to Python. I have Python 2.7 framework in `/Library/Frameworks`. I compile for Mac OS X 4, so I also have Python 2.3 in `/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks`. If I invoke `gcc` with `-F/Library/Frameworks` and peek at what it does with `-v`, I see the following:

```
ignoring duplicate directory "/Library/Frameworks"
  as it is a non-system directory that duplicates a system directory
<skipped>
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 <skipped>
 /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
 /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
```

I.e. it ignores my `/Library/Frameworks` because it's a duplicate (of the last path, which is a symlink to `/Library/Frameworks`) and then finds its own Python 2.3 framework before my 2.7.

I understand how to work around this (e.g. use `-I` with a full path to the include directory), but I'm somewhat puzzled by the search order. E.g. the linker (`ld`) [seems to search System/Library and Library in different order](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ld.1.html). I've tried to check manuals and Google, but, apparently, my skills are too low :)

I guess my questions are:

- Is this a normal behavior and why `gcc` searches in this order, while `ld` searches differently?
- Are there any framework-savvy methods to solve this, or I have to use the plain old `-I` flag?

Answer (score 4):

I think it is a bug that gcc and ld have a different ordering between the two.  You can have that fixed by filing a bug with llvm and/or Apple.  If Library were first, I think this would then do what you want.

Until then, you can do this:

```
$ mkdir Frameworks
$ ln -s /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework Frameworks
$ gcc -FFrameworks -E t.c
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a solution, it didn't occur to me I can use a symlink :) (Unfortunately, I lost control over that temporary account, so I cannot mark the answer as solution.)